# BigQuery Issue - LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join

Tags: google-bigquery

I am executing following query and getting *"LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join"*.

```
select p.*, q.* from (
    select a.* from table1 a
    left join
    (select distinct * from table2) b
    on a.name1=b.name2
    where a.name1 is not null) p
left join 
(SELECT distinct name3, amount FROM table3) q
on q.name3=p.name1 or q.name3=p.name2
```

How should I resolve it?

Comment: Have you tested your subqueries (a,b,p,q)? Which of them gives you this error?

Comment: Yes I tested the inner query works perfectly. But the outer query is giving error because of OR condition.

Comment: OR in WHERE works in BQ. Try without OR - separately both of conditions. Maybe one of them causes the error

Comment: I tested the individual condition works perfectly but OR condition in join is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `FULL JOIN` with additional `IS NOT NULL` condition will fit your case:

```
select p.*, q.*
from (
    select a.* from table1 a
    left join
    (select distinct * from table2) b
    on a.name1=b.name2
    where a.name1 is not null
) p
full join 
(SELECT distinct name3, amount FROM table3) q
on q.name3=p.name1 or q.name3=p.name2 
where p.name1 is not null or p.name2 is not null
```